# Why is my ASP.NET web app not connecting to my database .sdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I'm completely new to ASP and windows web development. I have a small web app written in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have set up a .sdf database with two tables.

When I run the application the data is being stored somewhere, but it's not in the database I made in visual studio.

My connection string in Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MoraleDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Morale.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and my controller method (hacking away trying to get something to work):

```
// POST: /MoraleScore/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(MoraleScoresDB moralescoresdb)
        {
            UsersDB test = new UsersDB();
            test.ID = 2;
            test.UserName = "jake";
            db.Users.Add(test);

            // Do checks on user to make sure that they have not already voted for this sprint, that they are allowed to vote...or before this?
            string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

            // Get username from list in database and set the right ID
            List<UsersDB> users = db.Users.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UsersDBs WHERE UserName = '" + username + "'").ToList();
            moralescoresdb.UserID = 1;/* users[0].ID;*/

            List<MoraleScoresDB> scores = db.MoraleScores.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MoraleScoresDBs;").ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.MoraleScores.Add(moralescoresdb);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            List<MoraleScoresDB> scores2 = db.MoraleScores.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MoraleScoresDBs;").ToList();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

With the debugger attached I can see that scores has one less item than scores2, but my database tables are empty. The "database" which is the sql server compact 4.0 Local Database is in my App_Data folder.

Let me know if you need any more info, as I'm totally new to this I have probably left out some info so sorry in advance. (The database is called "Morale.sdf" and is visible in the server explorer)

EDIT:

Here's the model:

```
namespace AgileWebsite.Models
{
    public class UsersDB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
    public class MoraleScoresDB
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Morale Score")]
        [Range(1, 10, ErrorMessage = "The score needs to be between 1 and 10.")]
        public int MoraleScore { get; set; }
    }

    public class MoraleDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MoraleDBContext()
            : base("MoraleDBContext")
        {}

        public DbSet<UsersDB> Users { get; set; } 
        public DbSet<MoraleScoresDB> MoraleScores { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Here's the top of the moraleScoreController (just above the post request create function you see above)

```
namespace AgileWebsite.Controllers
{
    public class MoraleScoreController : Controller
    {
        private MoraleDBContext db = new MoraleDBContext();
        private MoraleScoresDB moraleModel = new MoraleScoresDB();
```

UPDATE:

It turns out the databases that are automatically created are being created in the following location:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA

I think I was also using the wrong web.config file, there is one under "Views" folder and one that's just in the project, the latter is the one to use.

The name of of the connection should be the same as the derived DbContext class.

Comment: As an aside, if you could point me towards some good resources for this that would be great (I have a book coming in the post but it's always nice to have an online resource). Most of the stuff I've found doesn't really explain anything, it just gives you an example that I find difficult to extend as the logic is never explained and it's rather just a "copy me and press f5 ta da" type thing.

Comment: What is db in the code above? Is it an entity framework context?

Comment: What is db? can you add its class?

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming the db is a DbContext derived class (from the Entity Framework Library).)

Try adding...

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

after you add your user to the db.

Also, I had some issues with using server explorer with a compact db. It would drop the connection (showing the little red "x") and sometimes even if I selected "Refresh" on the connection I wouldn't see new data. I deleted the connection and then added it again (by double clicking on the sdf file) and then I could see the new data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, good spot on the saveChanges(). I tried deleting and reconnecting and it hasn't made any difference for me. I think I read somewhere that if you don't actually have a database it will just make one for you. I guess this is what is happening and can't get it to connect to the one I actually want it to.

Comment: Strange. Your db connection string looks correct. And you are calling 'base("MoraleDBContext")' as part of the ctor of your context?

Comment: I wasn't, but now I am, and it's still not working :( Another good spot though, not sure why I deleted/neglected to copy that bit.

Comment: Nothing else jumps out. Are you creating a transaction after you create and open the db context?

Comment: Not opening the dbcontext, maybe that's where I'm going wrong. How/where should I be doing that?

Comment: Can you post the code that creates the context? I can't tell from the code posted how the db context is getting created.

Comment: Grasping at straws here but check "db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString" and make sure it's "data source=|DataDirectory|\\MoraleDBContext.sdf".

Comment: It's not called MoraleDBContext.sdf. It's just called Morale.sdf. Do the names need to match?

Comment: I believe so. If your file is called "Morale.sdf" make sure you call 'base("Morale")' in the ctor of your context class.

Comment: Hmmm...don't really know where to go from here...sorry.

Comment: I'm reading a book on it at the moment so if I find out I'll let you know what was going on. May be how I'm checking the data rather than the connection being wrong, but I doubt it. It also doesn't seem to be trashing it between builds. Also, I'm not too fussed as when I come to ship it either will connect or won't and will be a lot easier to debug. Thanks for your help this far though :)